# How to keep data separate for businesses or groups of customers?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've done quit a bit of programming with php/mysql on small scale personal projects. However I'm working on my first commercial app that is going to allow customers or businesses to log in and perform CRUD operations. I feel like a total noob asking this question but I have never had to do this before and cannot find any relevant information on the net.

Basically, I've created this app and have a role based system set up on my data base. The problem that I'm running into is how to separate and fetch data for the relevant businesses or groups.

I can't, for example, set my queries up like this: get all records from example table where user id = user id, because that will only return data for that user and not all of the other users that are related to that business. I need a way to get all records that where created by users of a  particular business.

I'm thinking that maybe the business should have an id and I should form my queries like this: get all records from example where business id = business id. But I'm not even sure if that's a good approach.

*Is there a best practice or a convention for this sort data storing/fetching and grouping?
Note:Security is a huge issue here because I'm storing legal data.*

Also, I'm using the latest version of laravel 4 if that's any relevance.

I would like to hear peoples thoughts on this that have encountered this sort problem before and how they designed there database and queries to only get and store data related to that particular business.

**Edit:** I like to read and learn but cannot find any useful information on this topic - maybe I'm not using the correct search terms. So If you know of any good links pertaining to this topic, please post them too.

Comment: You're on the right path. Create a table that holds businesses and then associate users with those businesses. Each piece of data should then have an indexed column with the business ID to query against.

Comment: @BenD I guess that seems like the only logical approach. So for each table that's associated with a business I would create a foreign key linking to the business primary key? I think I remember reading a while back that it's not a good idea to link more than one related table to a tables primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, a business is defined within your system as a "group of users", and your whole system references data belonging to users as opposed to data belonging to a business.  You are looking to reference data that belongs to all users who belong to a particular business.  In this case, the best and most extensible way to do this would be to create two more tables to contain businesses and business-user relations.

For example, consider you have the following tables:

```
business         => Defines a business entity
    id (primary)
    name

    Entry: id=4, name=CompanyCorp

user             => Defines each user in the system
    id (primary)
    name

    Entry: id=1, name=Geoff
    Entry: id=2, name=Jane

business_user    => Links a user to a particular business
    user_id (primary)
    business_id (primary)

    Entry: user_id=1, business_id=4
    Entry: user_id=2, business_id=4
```

Basically, the `business_user` table defines relationships.  For example, Geoff is related to CompanyCorp, so a row exists in the table that matches their `id`'s together.  This is called a relational database model, and is an important concept to understand in the world of database development.  You can even allow a user to belong to multiple different companies.

To find all the names of users and their company's name, where their company's id = 4...

```
SELECT `user`.`name` as `username`, `business`.`name` as `businessname` FROM `business_user` LEFT JOIN `user` ON (`user`.`id` = `business_user`.`user_id`) LEFT JOIN `business` ON (`business`.`id` = `business_user`.`business_id`) WHERE `business_user`.`business_id` = 4;
```

Results would be:

```
   username    businessname
-> Geoff       CompanyCorp
-> Jane        CompanyCorp
```

I hope this helps!

===============================================================

**Addendum regarding "cases" per your response in the comments.**

You **could** create a new table for cases and then reference both business and user ids on separate columns in there, as the case would belong to both a user and a business, if that's all the functionality that you need.

Suppose though, exploring the idea of relational databases further, that you wanted multiple users to be assigned to a case, but you wanted one user to be elected as the "group leader", you could approach the problem as follows:

- Create a table "case" to store the cases
- Create a table "user_case" to store case-user relationships, just like in the business_user table.

Define the `user_case` table as follows:

```
user_case               => Defines a user -> case relationship
    user_id (primary)
    case_id (primary)
    role

    Entry: user_id=1, case_id=1, role="leader"
    Entry: user_id=2, case_id=1, role="subordinate"
```

You could even go further and define a table with definitions on what roles users can assume.  Then, you might even change the `user_case` table to use a `role_id` instead which joins data from yet another `role` table.

It may sound like an ever-deepening schema of very small tables, but note that we've added an extra column to the `user_case` relational table.  The bigger your application grows, the more your tables will grow laterally with more columns.  Trust me, you do eventually stop adding new tables just for the sake of defining relations.

To give a brief example of how flexible this can be, with a `role` table, you could figure out all the roles that a given user (where `user_id = 6`) has by using a relatively short query like:

```
SELECT `role`.`name` FROM `role` RIGHT JOIN `user_case` ON (`user_case`.`role_id` = `role`.`id`) WHERE `user_case`.`user_id` = 6;
```

If you need more examples, please feel free to keep commenting.

Comment: That makes sense. So, referring to this example, lets say I have another table called cases. When creating a case I would just get the business_id and current user id, and save the case with that business_id and user_id. Then, when I wanted to get and display all the cases for that business, I could just say: get all cases where business id = business_id(sudo code of course). Is that correct?

Comment: Maybe, that depends on what you're trying to accomplish (which I don't entirely understand yet).  Can you offer a definition of what a "case" is?

Comment: Okay, if you're talking about cases as sort of like "tasks" (as opposed to briefcases or something), then I've updated my answer with some new information that I hope helps you.

Comment: Sure, A case is simply a table that represents a legal case. The case table would have fields such as, case name, client name, insurance adjuster, etc. So there is going to be several cases in the database that are created by users, who are associated with a business, or more specifically, a law firm. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sounds like you're on track, then!  Using `WHERE user_id = x and business_id = y` sounds about right for your purpose.